# Multi-class classification using a single neural network with only one output neural

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

My problem has 3 classes.

I want to implement a single neural network, which has only one neural at the output layer, to classify these 3 classes.

Is there any way to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is truly classification you shouldn't implement output as one neuron, since you add strong a prior assumption about your class correlation. You can use one neuron only for binary class problems. Use 3 neurons outputs for 3-class problems. Check this example https://janakiev.com/notebooks/keras-iris/

Comment: I know that I should not but the problem is that I want to know whether there is any way to do that.

I edited my question.

Comment: If you want go this way. Split output values into 3 classes [(0; 0.33), (0.33, 0.66), (0.66, 1)] and treat your model as regression. Feed it with output values 0, 0.5 and 1  corresponding to specific classes.